# Regain access to lost Google Voice account

Tags: google-voice

I have a Google voice number that I haven't accessed for at least a year. In that year I lost access to the 2 email addresses I had and then signed up with Gmail. I know longer have the cell phone I used at the time of sign up either. Is there a way to find my log in info for my Google voice account?

I tried to have them send info to my email but since they don't have my new email it was not effective. Can anyone help?